# Finding number of errors in an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

How to find the number of errors(marked in red) in an eclipse project programmatically?

Comment: Open the Problems Window.Is that you want?

Comment: No,from the IProject i want to know the no of errors in the project in my worksapce. I have used the concept of IMarkers, but i am not able to determine programmtically how may errors are there??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two major steps:

1. You need an access to Eclipse API - write your own plugin for Eclipse or use a scripting plugin like [Groovy Monkey](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Monkey)
2. Using Eclipse API get problem markers for resource you intrested in - check this link: [How to work with resource markers](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm)

If you want to retrieve only JDT error markers you should write something like this:

```
public static IMarker[] calculateCompilationErrorMarkers(IProject project)
{
    ArrayList <IMarker> result = new ArrayList <IMarker>();
    IMarker[] markers = null;
    markers = project.findMarkers(IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
    for (IMarker marker: markers)
    {
        Integer severityType = (Integer) marker.getAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY);
        if (severityType.intValue() == IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR)
                result.add(marker);
    }
    return result.toArray(new IMarker[result.size()]);
}
```

Comment: What is the `IProject` parameter? How can I send it?